# simple question regarding divides

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Suppose a is an integer. If 5|2a then 5|a. Prove

So i just suppose that 5|2a and so 2a=5b for some b in the integers but i dont know where to go from here.

Thanks for help

Comment: $2a=5b$ implies that $5b$ is even.

Comment: so b must be even, so b=2k and then that gives a=5k?

Comment: Yes. And in this way you are done.

Comment: $5\mid 5a-2(2a) = a\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5\vert 2a \implies 2a = 5b \implies a = \frac{5b}{2}$$

By definition, $2a$ is even for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $5b$ (and subsequently $b$) must be even.

$$b = 2c \implies a = \frac{5(2c)}{2} = 5c$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $5$ and $2$ are relatively prime (by Bezout's lemma or a result of reversing Euclid's gcd algorithm), there exists integers $x, y$ such that
$$
5x+2y=1.
$$
Multiply through by $a$ to get that
$$
5ax+2ay=a
$$
As you noted $2a=5b$, so the LHS is divisible by $5$ and hence $5|a$ too.

Note that the same reasoning can be used to prove Euclid's lemma which states that if $n\mid ab$ and $n$ and $a$ are relatively prime, then $n\mid b$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

Since $5\mid 2a$, we also have $5\mid 3\cdot(2a)=6a$

Also $5\mid 5a$.

So $5\mid(6a-5a)=a$

Comment: if you go from 5|2a to 5|6a why cant you go from 5|2a to 5|1/2*2*a?

Comment: Because for any integers $a,b,c$, $a\mid b$ implies $a\mid bc$; but not necessarily $a\mid b/c$.